# Regular expression in HTML5 input pattern with German Umlaute

Tags: html, regex, validation, input

I try to allow only certain letters in the HTML input field including German Umlaute.

However, using:

```
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-#@.+_ \ä\ö\ü\Ä\Ö\Ü]" type="text" value="">
```

or alternatively:

```
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-#@.+_ äöüÄÖÜ]" type="text" value="">
```

Gives the error (in Chrome):

> Pattern attribute value [a-zA-Z0-9-#@.+_ \ä\ö\ü\Ä\Ö\Ü] is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[a-zA-Z0-9-#@.+_ \ä\ö\ü\Ä\Ö\Ü]/: Invalid escape

How to include the Umlaute in the input pattern attribute?

**Update:**

It works now. Escape the special characters: `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\+ äöüÄÖÜ]*"`

Comment: The "duplicate" question has nothing to do with Umlaute. Unfortunately some "moderators" are really not seeing the differences in some questions.

Answer (score 1):

Three errors in your regExp pattern.

1. \ä can't be escape by Browser like \b \s, because of  ä is not a special character.
2. while - is considered as a string instead of [from-to], it must be escaped as \-.

```
// don't need escape
. _ = * ^ $    etc.
```

Four character need to be escaped are :

```
// need escape
[ ] - \ .
```

3. need a * at the end of your pattern to match more than one character.

The - after 9 must be escaped.

```
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\-#@.+_ äöüÄÖÜ]*" type="text" value="">
```

Unicode flag used by default in pattern regExp in the current versions of Chrome and FF, and Browser will check your pattern is right or wrong.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode

Comment: Strange, I get an error. Chrome 110.0.5481.104. Even when using a simple pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9.-+ äöüÄÖÜ]` I get "pattern attribute value [a-zA-Z0-9.-+ äöüÄÖÜ] is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[a-zA-Z0-9.-+ äöüÄÖÜ]/: Range out of order in character class".

Comment: Update: It works now. I need to escape the special characters: `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\+ äöüÄÖÜ]"`

Comment: But it is not the solution yet. Entering a single word like "testing" does not allow the submit. Something is still wrong.

Comment: Your regexp means one of these characters, try to add a * in the end. pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\+ äöüÄÖÜ]*"

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works. Maybe update your answer and I can choose it as best. :) Thanks.

Comment: Actually, only - need be escaped, . and + don't.